# Dates less than or equal to 6 months old, but not including dates > today - 2 days

Tags: mysql, datetime

Using MySQl, I have a table with a datatype datetime column and
I need to select rows with a datetime < 6 months of current date, but also eliminate the first 2 days.

*EXAMPLE:*

For today 1/27/2017 -

I need records from 1/27/2017 to 7/27/2016 (That is an INTERVAL of 6 MONTHS), **minus** the first 2 days (1/26/2017 and 1/27/2017).

So my results will be a list of dates from 1/25/2017 to 7/27/2016.

*WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:*

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDateTime >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND (DATE(date_add(myDateTime, INTERVAL 2 DAY))) < DATE(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Should that work? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE(myDateTime) >= DATE(NOW() - interval 6 month + interval 2 day))`

Edit: Just saw you need it to be historical so adjust to:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE(myDateTime) BETWEEN DATE(NOW() - interval 6 month + interval 2 day) AND DATE(NOW())`

Comment: Hey Donii, Looks like you have an extra ")" or missing "(" in your answer. I'm not sure which it is. Thanks!